# The sum of digits of the number $8^{2460}$ is calculated,then the sum of the digits of the result is calculated and so on,until we get a single digit.

Tags: number-theory

The number $8^{2460}$ is written in a blackboard (it contains over $2,000$ digits, so we hope that the reader doesn't mind that we didn't write it out here). The sum of its digits is calculated, then the sum of the digits of the result is calculated and so on, until we get a single digit. What is this digit?

Okay, I been thinking about this problem, however I have no idea what formula I have to apply to do it. I thought about writing out $8^{2460}$ as $(8^{41})^{60}$ but from here I do not know how to proceed. I will appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $8\equiv -1\pmod{9}$. So our enormous number is congruent to $1$ modulo $9$, since the exponent is even.  Thus the answer is $1$.

We are using the fact that the sum of the decimal digits of a number is congruent to the number modulo $9$. This is relatively easy to show by using the observation that $10\equiv 1\pmod{9}$, and therefore every power of $10$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $9$. So for example $5438=5\times 10^3+4\times 10^2+3\times 10^1+8\times 10^0\equiv 5+4+3+8\pmod{9}$.

**Remark:** Back in the bad old days before calculators, the fact that the digit sum of any $n$ is congruent to $n$ modulo $9$ was used as a primitive check on the accuracy of computations. The procedure was called "casting out nines."

Comment: Even powers of 8 yield sum of 1. Odd powers actually result in sum of 8. Power is OP's question is even so 1 is right answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Some $40$ years ago, casting out nines was something one learned and used from very early on. Things change! (But error detection/correction is more important than ever.)